# Why do test:units and test:functionals insist on running in development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, environment-variables

I'm trying to test some environment-specific settings (middleware to be specific, but it doesn't seem to matter), but I'm having trouble getting the tests to run in the correct environment. The symptoms:

- If I run `ruby test/unit/my_test.rb`, all is fine because the first thing it does is require `test/test_helper.rb`, which sets the environment to `"test"` and then loads the Rails environment.
- If I run `rake test`, the first batch (functionals) run fine, but the second batch (units) fail. The failure is that `ENV['RAILS_ENV]` somehow gets unset between batches, then `config/environment.rb` sees that none is set and uses the default of `"development"`. The environment is correct at the beginning of `config/environment.rb` and at the beginning of the configuration block in that file, but wrong by the end. I can tell by using a `puts` or by deleting `config/development.rb` causing it to not find the file.
- If I run `rake test:units`, I get the same problem as the second batch of `rake test` (that is, all fail)
- If I run `rake test:functionals`, I get the same as for `rake test:units`
- If I run `rake test RAILS_ENV=test` or `rake test:units RAILS_ENV=test` or `rake test:functionals RAILS_ENV=test`, all is fine!

One thing I tried that doesn't work at all is the following:

```
# in Rakefile:
task :set_test_env { ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test' }
Rake::Task[:test].prerequisites.unshift :set_test_env
# and similarly for other test tasks
```

I even tried creating a separate one of those `:set_test_env` tasks for *each test task* so that I was sure it would get called before each one instead of just once. Still no dice. It *does* get called, and the environment is correct at the beginning of `config/environment.rb` but something goes wrong inside.

I have no calls to set `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` in my code anywhere.

Comment: Based on your comments about environment.rb and deleting development.rb, it might help to see your environment.rb file and the stack trace or error message related to the development.rb file missing.

Comment: It's pretty easy to do for yourself. (1) start a new Rails app. (2) in config/environtments/development.rb, add the line "raise 'development!'" at the end. (3) run "rake tests" (or just "rake") from the command line.

Comment: Ah. I thought maybe you had a special case, but the problem can be reproduced in a blank app. Fun puzzle. :)

So far the best I can tell is that the Rails system is loaded up during test prep in order to check for pending DB migrations and that this is setting RAILS_ENV set to 'development' if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] is not already set.

Comment: It can't _quite_ be that simple. If it were, then that example code at the end of my post (task :set_test_env { ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test' }; Rake::Task[:test].prerequisites.unshift :set_test_env) would solve the problem, which it doesn't. But we're on the right track.

Comment: OK. I was able, somehow, to get this problem to reproduce at some point, but I think maybe I had an older version of Rails? Trying it just now with Rails 2.3.2, Ruby 1.8.7 on Ubuntu 9.04... it doesn't happen in a blank project. I get a missing schema.db complaint, run rake db:migrate, and then rake test works. What environment and versions are you running?

Comment: ruby --version -> ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [universal-darwin9.0].  gem list rails -> rails (2.3.2, 1.2.6).

Comment: The issue is that you have stuff in development.rb that clobbers your tests. Find somewhere more appropriate to put that stuff, and your problem is solved. Where to move it depends on what, exactly, it's doing, so my advice is to post your development.rb.

Answer (score 5):

To give you a full answer I would have to take a look at the code, but I'll try to give you some clues that might be helpful.

First of all `rake test` and all the other variants (`test:units`, `test:functionals` etc.) work as follows

1. Rake process is invoked and task `test` is executed in **the current environment** (which is development by default), that's why `development.rb` is always read.
2. The Rake task invokes the test loader **in a separate child process** (you can verify this with `ps` or `pstree`), this is where the `test_helper.rb` is sourced and environment is set to test.

When you run `ruby test/unit/my_test.rb` the first step is skipped, so it looks like the problem lies there. Maybe you do something in `development.rb` that has side effects for the subprocess?

Answer (score 2):

I pretty much always want to force my tests to run themselves and their prerequisites in the "test" environment, especially when ENV['RAILS_ENV'] is set to any of the common defaults (to avoid catastrophic accidents), but I also want to be able to run tests on, say, an environment named "v_2_0_maint_test" or something like that by calling `rake test:units RAILS_ENV=v_2_0_maint_test` on the command line.

So I have a test_tasks.rake file that prepends a prerequisite onto each of the test tasks that I'm interested in. Since this prerequisite is prepended, any other prerequisites (e.g. db:test:prepare, db:fixtures:load) run in the same environment. This claims the virtue of affecting only the tests you want to affect, **and** their prerequisites.

```
namespace :test do |n|
  [ n[:units], n[:functionals], n[:integration] ].each do |t|
    t.prerequisites.unshift(:set_test_env_dammit)
  end

  task :set_test_env_dammit do |t|
    if [ nil, "", "development", "staging", "production" ].index ENV['RAILS_ENV']
      RAILS_ENV = "test"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the test_helper.rb file I have the code

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
```

If you do not have that line then the system problem would run in the default environment (i.e. development).

Comment: Nope, got that. It comes default in Rails. And all my test files include that file. But it's definitely a good thing to check.

Answer (score 0):

Search through your entire project for RAILS_ENV and its variants. See if you set it somewhere in your application or in your tests.

Also, what platform are you running on? Can you run tests on another machine and see if the results are the same?

If this is a relatively recent development and you're using a RCS like Git or SVN, you should look through the recent commits, and if you're specifically using Git, you should look into git bisect. If you're not using an RCS, you should be.

If this is truly a fresh app problem, then it's probably a problem with your environment.

What plugins and gems do you have installed/configured? Can we see the backtrace?

Comment: As I said in a comment above: It's pretty easy to do for yourself. (1) start a new Rails app. (2) in config/environtments/development.rb, add the line "raise 'development!'" at the end. (3) run "rake tests" (or just "rake") from the command line.

So it's not a problem with my code. And I just tried it again with a fresh installation of the Rails 2.3.3 gem.

Comment: Gaius, unfortunately your "Simple test" is not proving the point. When rake starts it will do a number of things before it loads the test helper. These tasks will be done within the currently active environment. Which by default will be development, some of these predicate tasks will load the default environment. Your simple case will not demonstrate the point if you set RAILS_ENV in the shell using export RAILS_ENV=test before running rake

Answer (score -1):

I do not actually believe that you have an issue here at all. I believe that at some time you spotted that your rake task was actually hitting the development environment and you started to try and work out why that was the case. You then added a line within the development config file to raise an exception and this is why your rake tests are failing.

If you remove the line that is raising an exception then you may find that the tests all run succesfuly.

If you try the following you may find that it explains the issue.

1. Set the environment to development (Just for purposes of the trace)

   export RAILS_ENV=development
2. Remove all lines that artificially
   raise exceptions in your environment
   files.
3. Add the following line to the end of
   each file in config/environments

   ```
   puts "**** In #{ENV['RAILS_ENV']} environment config ****"
   ```
4. Add the following line to the test/test_helper.rb just below the line that sets the environment to test.

   ```
   puts "**** Loading test helper **** Environment = #{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}"
   ```
5. Run rake using the trace option to watch the tasks execute with a trace of the currently active environment.

   ```
   rake -t test
   ```
6. Examine the output to determine where your environment is not set correctly.
7. Run the tests again but this time set the environment directly before running the tests using

   export RAILS_ENV=test

If you really do have an issue then perhaps you should post up the output of the rake -t with the tracing code in.

This is the output of my tests in a brand new project with some minimal testing in place. You will notice that before the actual tests are run the environment is always "test"

```
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
**** In development environment config ****
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:units
**** Loading test helper **** Environment = test
**** In test environment config ****
Loaded suite /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.
Finished in 0.071771 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
** Invoke test:functionals (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare
** Execute test:functionals
**** Loading test helper **** Environment = test
**** In test environment config ****
Loaded suite /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.....
Finished in 0.133776 seconds.

5 tests, 6 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
** Invoke test:integration (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare
** Execute test:integration
```

Comment: As I say in the first sentence of my question, the problem is that in my _actual_ app I have lots of initialization in my development.rb that clobbers all over my tests. Removing my debugging "raise" line causes all sorts of havoc because I'm trying to interact with live (development) systems rather than fake versions.

Comment: But with the raise line in it is always going to fail as rake is invoked in the "Current environment". So as soon as it loads the current environment (development) it will raise the exception.

Comment: Gaius, the issue is that you have stuff in development.rb that clobbers your tests. Find somewhere more appropriate to put that stuff, and your problem is solved. Where to move it depends on what, exactly, it's doing.

Comment: @Sarah Mei: it baffles me why I should have to worry about what's in my development.rb when I'm running tests. Tests should run *exclusively* in the test environment.